# How can I see what objects are declared at the root level in a Javascript VM

Tags: javascript

How can I see what objects are declared at root level in a Javascript VM, say, in Firefox browser, node.js or otto ? What command should I type to show this info?

Comment: `console.log(this)`?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, makes sense. but would that be all of it?

Comment: are you looking for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object?

Comment: That would show all properties of the global object. It really depends on what you mean by "objects ... declared". Do you mean constructors?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, well, I typed "this", pressed ENTER, and got this output: `"<environment [object environment]>"` . Further attempts to show `this.environment`  produced `undefined` output. I am using javascript console of `geth`, Ethereum client,it uses an `otto` virtual machine

Comment: Agree this would be the easiest way.  if you are overwhelmed, you could always do something like Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this).map(n => this[n]).filter(o => typeof o === "object" && o); to trim the list a little.

Comment: @Woody,`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)` is better. This is what I got in my environement: `["eval", "parseInt", "parseFloat", "isNaN", "isFinite", "decodeURI", "decodeURIComponent", "encodeURI", "encodeURIComponent", "escape", "unescape", "Object", "Function", "Array", "String", "Error", "JSON", "undefined", "NaN", "Infinity", "console", "_setTimeout", "_setInterval", "setTimeout", "setInterval", "clearTimeout", "clearInterval", "loadScript", "inspect", "jeth", "BigNumber", "XMLHttpRequest", "require", "Web3", "web3", "eth", "personal", "rpc", "txpool", "admin", "debug", "miner", "net"]`

Comment: That looks about right, if you want to figure out if those things are objects or functions etc, you would need to do a little more digging, but looks like you are on the right track.

Comment: @georg , yes, that's what I am looking for, but in my javascript environment there is no `global` , `Window`, `Worker` or `WorkerGlobalScope` , so I don't know how is it called, but it should exist.